# Draggableview number fornat exception

Tags: android, draggable

Below is my XML code:

```
<com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:draggable_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/draggable_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        draggable_view:enable_minimized_horizontal_alpha_effect="true"
        draggable_view:top_view_height="200dp"
        draggable_view:top_view_id="@+id/image"
        draggable_view:bottom_view_id="@+id/ll"
        draggable_view:top_view_margin_bottom="50dp"
        draggable_view:top_view_margin_right="10dp"
        draggable_view:top_view_resize="true"
        draggable_view:top_view_x_scale_factor="2.3"
        draggable_view:top_view_y_scale_factor="2.3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:background="@drawable/imgone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.github.pedrovgs.DraggableView>
```

I supposed to have dragabble view in my app.while running my app the following error throws:

```
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: For input string: "200.0dip"
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "200.0dip"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in that random github library you're using.  It doesn't see 200dp as a number, presumably because its not expecting dp there.  You're going to have to fix it yourself or contact the author and see if he's willing to do so.  Or not use dp, and code around the scaling issues somehow.

Comment: https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel/issues/131        Gone through the above site. Will degrading my Studio works?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with your android studio-  its a bug (or missing feature) in the library

Comment: any other alternate library?